# Swift - Make Sprite Kit Node to only be affected by gravity?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode8

I have an SKShapeNode with a physicsBody. I want this node to **only** be affected by gravity and **not** be affected collisions. Is this possible?

I have tried `node.isDynamic = false` but that means that the node is **not** affected by gravity. I have tried setting `.collisionBitMask = 0` but the node falls out of the screen. I have searched SO and Google but can't find anything...

**Help!**

Comment: A node will not by affected by collisions if you set its physics body's collisionBitMask to zero by `node.physicsBody?.collisionTestMask = 0`. Impulses are applied with code, so I'm not sure why you need the node to not be affected by them.

Comment: @0x141E You're right about the impulses, hadn't meant to include them. I've tried setting the `.collisionBitMask = 0`, but that means that the node falls out of the screen.

Comment: If you have a floor or screen border, you'll need to set the collision bit mask to the same value as the border's categoryBitMask.

Comment: @0x141E I've tried what you've suggested but the node is still falling out of the screen.

Comment: Does the border have a physics body?

Comment: @0x141E Edited question

Comment: Try setting the categoryBitMask for the edge loop and set the collisionBitMask of the character to that same value

Comment: @0x141E **Thanks, that worked!** Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `categoryBitMask` for the edge physicsBody and set the `collisionBitMask` of the node to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

```
node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:node.size];
node.physicsBody.dynamic= false;
node.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true;
```

Comment: I have tried this but the `.dynamic = false` is rendering the `.affectedByGravity = true` useless. It doesn't work :-(